# If 5'th fascist rule enacted with frustrated populace, VETO POWER is granted or not?

Tags: secret-hitler

pdf rules says: "Immediately reveal the Policy on top of the Policy deck and enact it. Any power granted by this Policy is ignored, but the Election Tracker resets, and existing term-limits are forgotten."
but I don't understand veto power in next rounds must be granted or not?!

Answer (score 1):

The veto power doesn't depend on how the polices got enacted just that they did. After five have been enacted if both the president and chancellor agree to veto it will happen.

https://www.secrethitler.com/assets/Secret_Hitler_Rules.pdf

> The Veto Power is a special rule that comes into
> effect after five Fascist Policies have been
> enacted. For all Legislative Sessions after the
> fifth Fascist Policy is enacted, the Executive
> branch gains a permanent new ability to discard
> all three Policy tiles if both the Chancellor
> and President agree.

> The President draws three Policy tiles,
> discards one, and passes the remaining two to
> the Chancellor as usual. Then Chancellor may,
> instead of enacting either Policy, say “I wish
> to veto this agenda.” If the President consents
> by saying, “I agree to the veto,” both Policies
> are discarded and the President placard passes
> to the left as usual. If the President does not
> consent, the Chancellor must enact a Policy
> as normal.

> Each use of the Veto Power represents an
> inactive government and advances the Election
> Tracker by one.